# SQL RAISERROR under CASE

Tags: sql, error-handling, sql-server-2016, raiserror

I'm trying to use a RAISERROR in my query but I can't get it working. No doubt I'm trying to do this completely the wrong way.

For example, in the code below I would like it to terminate the query if the DestType field is blank or NULL.

```
SELECT TOP 1
    DocEntry,
    DocNum,
    CAST(DocDate AS DATE) AS [DocDate],
    CAST(DocDueDate AS date) AS [ShipDate],
    Comments,
    DestType
FROM ....
```

I tried putting it in a CASE WHEN IN type thing but that didn't work.

Many thanks!

Comment: CASE is designed to return a value, its not for control of flow.  Store the value in a variable and test after the select with an IF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RAISERROR` is a statement which cannot be inlined.

With SQL-Server 2016 (as tagged) you can use

```
BEGIN TRY
    Do Something here
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    RAISERROR ...parameters...
END CATCH
```